# Selenium script clicks on continue button, but webpage doesn't advance

Tags: python, selenium, dom, webdriver

I am trying to automate the checkin process for United Airlines.  When I get to the continue button, the script clicks it, but the page doesn't advance.  Any ideas on how to force this?

My script thus far:

```
from concurrent.futures import thread
from curses import KEY_ENTER
from time import sleep, thread_time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/jeff/chromedriver/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.united.com/en/us/checkin')
driver.find_element('name', 'confirmationNumberModel.number').send_keys('xxxxx')
driver.find_element('name', 'confirmationNumberModel.lastName').send_keys('LastName')

sleep(3)

driver.find_element('xpath', "//button[@type='submit' and text()='Continue']").click()
```

Comment: I also tried the following:                                                                                                                                 
driver.find_element('xpath', "//button[@type='submit' and text()='Continue']").click()
sleep(2)
driver.find_element('xpath', "//button[@type='submit' and text()='Continue']").submit()     now I just get the spinning circle of death when the page tries to load

Answer (score 0):

You could try this workaround instead of clicking:

```
driver.find_element('xpath', "//button[@type='submit' and text()='Continue']").sendKeys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Tried that one too, but it didn't work either.  I'm at a loss on this one